# Full text catalog - certain value does not result in a catalog entry

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I'm confused about a Problem with a certain value in a simple table containing addresses, that this City named "Höchst" would not be found in a full text search

The Statement:

```
select id, city0
from addresses
where contains (city0, 'Höchst')
```

returns nothing.

Other cities with the same character "ö" (e.g. "Mönchhai") involved are found.

So I looked at the catalog:

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_index_keywords (Db_id('<dbname>'),
                                         OBJECT_ID('<dbname>.dbo.ADDRESSES'))
where column_id=25 and display_term like 'h%'
```

Returns the Display Terms (excerpt)

```
himmel          25  1
himmelpforten   25  1
hof             25  15
hoffnung        25  1
hoffnungstal    25  1
hohberg         25  1
```

=> There is no entry for "Höchst"

searching for 'mo%' Shows a result like

```
moncaprice  25  2
monchhai    25  4
moormerland 25  1
moosburg    25  1
```

=> There is an entry for "Mönchhai".You can see, that the 'ö' is converted into 'o'.

Why doesn't this happen with "Höchst"?

There is not fulltext stoplist.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm confused. How do you know that city **Höchst** is actually in the table?

Comment: It's my test database and I'm the only one working in it. Actually I did the following test: <br> - first I changed the city0 value to "Höchs" by just removing the last letter <br> - then I searched for "Höchs" using CONTAINS => "Höchs" was found!<br> - then I queried the catalog and found "hochs" in it <br> - then I chaned the value back to "Höchst" and "hochs" disappeared out of the catalog <br> What am I missing? Is there a stoplist I did'nt fid yet?